# Create a FrameworkElement out of an BitmapImage file, and then destroy?

Tags: wpf, frameworkelement

I have a WPF project, which we using some WindowsForm control(PivotTable from OWC, Office Web Component). However, since the PivotTable doesn't support print very well, the only way we can think of is to print the image file PivotTable exports(another way is to print from exported Excel file, but we want to avoid it since it is not guaranteed that Excel is installed on the machine).

We already have one print project, which will print WPF `ElementFramework` nicely. So I want to use that piece of code. Now my question is: how I can generate a `FrameworkElement` out of a `BitmapImage` from code. Since this `FrameworkElement` is purely for printing, so I guess I must create it from the code, probably assign a parent to it, not show it on the screen, and after the printing destroy the `FrameworkElement` so that ultimately I can delete the temp `BitmapImage` file.

So this is beyond my knowledge. I don't even know whether that's a proper way: create a UI element for some non-UI related work? Any advice on that? Thanks!

Comment: do i understand you correctly you want to Convert a `BitmapImage` to an `FrameworkElement`?

Comment: @WiiMaxx , yes. But this FrameworkElement doesn't belong to any actual UI element so the more crucial part is how to destroy it afterwards

Comment: i would mention if non other object hold an reference to it the GarbagCollector will take it

Answer (score 0):

You should load the temp image file's bytes into memory and create a `Image` from those bytes.
Your `Image` will not use the temp file directly and you can delete it immediately after reading the bytes, the rest is `GarbageCollector's` job. Here is a function to create your `BitmapImage` from bytes:

```
        public static BitmapImage GetImageFromByteArray(byte[] rawImageBytes)
        {
            BitmapImage imageSource = null;

            try
            {
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(rawImageBytes))
                {
                    stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
                    BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                    bi.BeginInit();
                    bi.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
                    bi.StreamSource = stream;
                    bi.EndInit();
                    imageSource = bi;
                }
            }
            catch (System.Exception)
            {
            }

            return imageSource;
        }
```

And use it like this:
`testImage.Source = GetImageFromByteArray(rawImageBytes);`

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like a better way. But then the questions becomes how can I destroy the Image object? Since all of this happens in my ViewModel class, it doesn't have any knowledge or any member of other FrameworkElement where I can attach and finally detach the Image to destroy it. Obviously I don't want this object hanging in the memory.

Comment: The `GC` will take care of your `Image` object. It is a simple `Object` that is not a member of the `LogicalTree` and will be freed by `CG`.